# Random Color in objects using ProRender

Tags: materials, color, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I am creating several objects and I want each of them to have different colors based on a color spectrum. To do so in the Shading tab I select all the objects and assign them a material. I then connect the Principled BSDF node with ColorRamp. Since I am using ProRender I do not have the Object Info input. Therefore I have using the RPR Lookup with Random Color selected. I then connect RPR Lookup to ColorRamp. In ColorRamp I selected three colors, Red, Cyan, and Blue. However, on the objects instead of showing any of these colors on each of the objects it only shows white.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Blender 2.82a
Lastest version of ProRender[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Random Color" already produces a color, not a random numeric value like the missing Object Info node, so I think it doesn't play well with the ColorRamp node.

If I connect the "Random Color" output of the RPR Lookup node directly to Base Color on Principled BSDF, I get random colors as expected.

[image]

If you'd like to get back the palette control that ColorRamp offers you, you can pass the output of "Random Color" into the "RGB to BW" node (found under Converter) and then pass that output into ColorRamp as shown below.

[image]